# Cannot find module 'casper' with 1.1 beta

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

This command was working:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.0.2/libexec/bin/casperjs myfile.coffee
```

Now I want to use 1.1 like so:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/bin/casperjs myfile.coffee
```

But now I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'casper'

  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require
```

People reporting this error are trying to invoke casper by running phantomjs, but as you see I am running casperjs directly. What gives?

**UPDATE**

In case it provides a clue, when I call `require = patchRequire(require)` on the first line of my script, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'require.patched')

  /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/bin/bootstrap.js:197 in patchRequire
```

Comment: Your paths seem to be non-standard. Is everything from the casperjs package contained in the libexec dir? How did you install it. What linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I installed it on my dev machine (OSX) as instructed here http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html, so using ```brew install casperjs --devel```

Comment: The ```libexec``` folder for 1.1 has the same things as 1.0.2 except ```Makefile``` and ```docs```. The ```libexec/modules``` folder has the same files except it also has a ```vendors``` folder, which contains ```coffeescript.js```.